# Error in parsing, update multiple columns in 1 line

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Input to `pd.read_clipboard()`

```
Ratanhia ,30c x2, 200c x2
Aloe ,30c x2, 200c x2
Nitric Acid ,30c x2, 200c x 2
Sedum Acre ,200c x2, 30c x2
Paeonia ,200c x2, 30c x2
Sulphur ,200c x2, 30c x2
Hamamelis ,30c x1, 200c x1
Aesculus ,30c x1, 200c x1⁠⁠⁠⁠
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None, sep=',')
df.columns = ['Medicine','power30c','power200c']
df.power30c=df.power30c.apply(lambda x: x[-1])
df.power200c=df.power200c.apply(lambda x: x[-1])
print df
```

Output:

```
       Medicine power30c power200c
0     Ratanhia         2         2
1         Aloe         2         2
2  Nitric Acid         2         2
3   Sedum Acre         2         2
4      Paeonia         2         2
5      Sulphur         2         2
6    Hamamelis         1         1
7     Aesculus         1         �
```

Questions:

1. Why that `�` in the last row?
2. How to modify more than 1 column in 1 line?

```
df[['power30c','power200c']] = df[['power30c','power200c']].apply(lambda x: x[-1])

Throws error:

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 3 elements
```

Python Version: 2.7, Pandas: 0.19, IPython: 4

Comment: what happens if there is a new line after last line?

Comment: @piRSquared Resolved. Copied that text from whatsapp. That was the reason. The last `x1` was something else under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parameter `skipinitialspace`:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',',
                       names=['Medicine','power30c','power200c'], 
                       skipinitialspace=True)
print (df)
       Medicine power30c power200c
0     Ratanhia    30c x2   200c x2
1         Aloe    30c x2   200c x2
2  Nitric Acid    30c x2  200c x 2
3   Sedum Acre   200c x2    30c x2
4      Paeonia   200c x2    30c x2
5      Sulphur   200c x2    30c x2
6    Hamamelis    30c x1   200c x1
7     Aesculus    30c x1   200c x1
```

And then [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df[['power30c','power200c']] = df[['power30c','power200c']].apply(lambda x: x.str[-1])
print (df)
       Medicine power30c power200c
0     Ratanhia         2         2
1         Aloe         2         2
2  Nitric Acid         2         2
3   Sedum Acre         2         2
4      Paeonia         2         2
5      Sulphur         2         2
6    Hamamelis         1         1
7     Aesculus         1         1
```

Comment: Thanks. Still getting that `�`.

Comment: Still getting it after `skipinitialspace`. Brb in some time.

Comment: Hmmm, I test it without `skipinitialspace` and for me it works too very nice, so it means there has to be different problem.

Comment: I use python 3 and pandas 0.19.2.

Comment: Resolved. Copied that text from whatsapp. That was the reason. The last `x1` was something else under the hood.

Comment: Super, I check plain text of input in question and there it was nice, so I think problem was with os or browser. ;)

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: Hey! look at this user. He is your subset :P http://stackoverflow.com/users/3019689/jez

Comment: @MYGz - Very nice ;) And btw thank you for accepting!

Comment: Your answer was more helpful :). MaxU noticed 1 more thing. Check his answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is some characters at the end of the text you posted. If you do the copy from here it works:

```
Ratanhia ,30c x2, 200c x2
Aloe ,30c x2, 200c x2
Nitric Acid ,30c x2, 200c x 2
Sedum Acre ,200c x2, 30c x2
Paeonia ,200c x2, 30c x2
Sulphur ,200c x2, 30c x2
Hamamelis ,30c x1, 200c x1
Aesculus ,30c x1, 200c x1
```

When I use the text you posted, you can see the extra characters:

```
In [88]: df.power200c[6]
Out[88]: '200c x1'
In [89]: df.power200c[7]
Out[89]: '200c x1\xe2\x81\xa0\xe2\x81\xa0\xe2\x81\xa0\xe2\x81\xa0'
```

Comment: Resolved. Copied that text from whatsapp. That was the reason. The last `x1` was something else under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

This is a syntax error

```
    Ratanhia ,30c x2, 200c x2
    Aloe ,30c x2, 200c x2
    Nitric Acid ,30c x2, 200c x2
    Sedum Acre ,200c x2, 30c x2
    Paeonia ,200c x2, 30c x2
    Sulphur ,200c x2, 30c x2
    Hamamelis ,30c x1, 200c x1
    Aesculus ,30c x1, 200c x1
```

The last character in your table referring non-utf-8. Please find corrected one above. After solve this length mismatch issue resolved automatically.

Comment: Resolved. Copied that text from whatsapp. That was the reason. The last `x1` was something else under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I think those solution don't address the fact that you have mixed data in "power*" columns:

```
       Medicine power30c power200c
0     Ratanhia    30c x2   200c x2
1         Aloe    30c x2   200c x2
2  Nitric Acid    30c x2  200c x 2
3   Sedum Acre   200c x2    30c x2   #  / NOTE: mixed up values
4      Paeonia   200c x2    30c x2   # <  "200c" is in the "power30c" column
5      Sulphur   200c x2    30c x2   #  \ and "30c" is in the "power200c" column
6    Hamamelis    30c x1   200c x1
7     Aesculus    30c x1   200c x1
```

Here is another solution:

```
In [34]: df
Out[34]:
       Medicine power30c     power200c
0     Ratanhia    30c x2       200c x2
1         Aloe    30c x2       200c x2
2  Nitric Acid    30c x2      200c x 2
3   Sedum Acre   200c x2        30c x2
4      Paeonia   200c x2        30c x2
5      Sulphur   200c x2        30c x2
6    Hamamelis    30c x1       200c x1
7     Aesculus    30c x1   200c x1⁠⁠⁠⁠

In [35]: (df.set_index('Medicine')
    ...:    .stack()
    ...:    .str.extract(r'(\d+)c\s+x\s*(\d+)', expand=True)
    ...:    .reset_index(level=1, drop=1)
    ...:    .pivot(columns=0, values=1)
    ...:    .add_prefix('power')
    ...:    .add_suffix('c')
    ...:    .reset_index()
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[35]:
0      Medicine power200c power30c
0     Aesculus          1        1
1         Aloe          2        2
2    Hamamelis          1        1
3  Nitric Acid          2        2
4      Paeonia          2        2
5     Ratanhia          2        2
6   Sedum Acre          2        2
7      Sulphur          2        2
```

Comment: As gntoni has pointed out. When I copied the text from whatsapp, there was 1 additional character appended at the end of last `x1`. That was causing the issue. `30c` is potency and `x2` is multiplied by `2`.

Comment: @MYGz, my point was about mixed values in `power30c` and `power200c` columns, for example for: `['Sedum Acre', 'Paeonia', 'Sulphur']` - my solution addresses this issue

Comment: Oh. Cool! Since the numbers were all same didn't notice.